# Definition of quadratic residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory

According to Wikipedia, $q$ is a quadratic residue $\mod n$ if there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv q \mod n$.  Some other sources add the assumption that $q$ and $n$ are coprime.  Which is correct?

Comment: Which other sources...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Here:http://www2.latech.edu/~schroder/slides/number_theory/22_quadratic_residues.pdf, and here:http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/453.spring11/nt-notes4.pdf

Comment: There is not uniformity.

Comment: I see, @user68667 . Thanks. Certainly the most interesting cases happen with the units modulo $\,n\,$ but I wouldn't avoind the other ones...

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the difference between the two definitions  is not substantial.

Let $(q,n)=d$ and $\frac qQ=\frac nN=d$ so that $(Q,N)=1$

$$\text{So, }x^2\equiv q\pmod n-->(1)\iff x^2=q+u\cdot n\text{ where } u \text{ is some integer }$$

$$\implies x^2= Qd+u\cdot Nd=d(Q+u\cdot N) $$

Now, if $d=a\cdot D^2$(say) where  $D$  is some integer and integer $a$ is square-free.

$$\text{So, }\frac{x^2}{D^2}=a(Q+u\cdot N) \text{ which is an integer}$$

$\implies D^2\mid x^2\iff D\mid x\implies \frac xD$ is some integer $=y$(say)

$$\text{So, }\frac{y^2}a\equiv Q+u\cdot N \text{ which is an integer}$$

As $a$ is sqaure-free,  $a\mid y^2\iff a\mid y\implies \frac ya$ is some integer $=z$(say)

$$\text{So, }a\cdot z^2= Q+u\cdot N \equiv Q\pmod N,$$
$$z^2\equiv a^{-1}\cdot Q\pmod N-->(2)\text{ where} (Q,N)=1$$

So, we can always find an integer $z$ satisfying $(2)$ for each integer $x$ satisfying $(1)$ and vice-versa.